# Why do the Hawkmen have rocket cycles?

Tags: movie, flash-gordon

In the 1980 cult classic *Flash Gordon*, a race of winged Viking-like warriors called Hawkmen feature heavily in the story.  Flash is stranded on their homeworld, which actually seems to be a single floating palace, when the evil Emperor Ming attacks it.  The Hawkmen fly away, because they have wings and stuff, and Flash is left behind.

Just before the Hawkmen's kingdom is destroyed, Flash crawls into the underbelly of the palace and finds a rocket cycle - basically a flying jet ski - and escapes just in the nick of time.

[image]

I have never understood why the Hawkmen, who can fly under their own power, apparently with little or no effort, have rocket cycles.  They don't need machines to fly, so why bother buying/building, maintaining, and storing them?

I would understand if they had something like an airplane - it can carry more weight than a Hawkman alone, and possibly travel faster than a Hawkman could.  The rocket cycle is slow, and it can't carry much more than a person or two plus a backpack or something.  We never see the Hawkmen using a rocket cycle, and as far as we know, they only have one or two of them.  Hawkmen fly fast enough to mount an attack on the War Rocket *Ajax*, and their wings don't move in flight, so it would appear that they can fly without expending any effort or energy.  The rocket cycles don't seem to offer anything that the Hawkmen themselves don't already have.

### So why do the Hawkmen have these particular vehicles?

Comment: Beats me! Sort of the same way that humans, who can walk the Earth with their own feet/under their own power, would never develop a method of terrestrial locomotion... like all those far-fetched "cars," "buses," "trains," and "bicycles" you read about on the spectulative fiction sites: *totally* unbelievable!

Comment: @Lexible - The difference is that the Hawkmen seem to fly without even moving their wings, and they fly fast enough to attack the War Rocket Ajax.  The rocket cycle seems to move slower than the Hawkmen, and there is no evidence that the Hawkmen themselves ever use the rocket cycles.  If we could walk as fast as cars drive, and without expending any significant effort, we probably wouldn't have cars.

Comment: And endurance? How long can the Hawkmen fly? Freightage? How much can they carry? Wounded or disabled Hawkmen? How do they get about?

Comment: @Lexible  If Ming the Merciless was attacking your house, would you walk or drive away?  I would drive.  The Hawkmen just fly off with their wings.  Again, they don't seem to need endurance, because they don't appear to spend any energy in flying.  We never see them use a rocket cycle.  And you can't really carry anything on a rocket cycle anyway - it's like a jet ski.

Comment: Which is utterly irrelevant to the question of *why powered flight vehicles would exist*.

Comment: @Lexible - Nonsense.  They don't seem to have spaceships or aircraft capable of carrying cargo.  They have flying jet skis.  A cargo vessel would make sense, a flying jet ski does not.  As far as we know, they only have *one* rocket cycle, possibly two.  That's not enough to make a significant contribution to moving matériel or people around.

Comment: Given that the world I live in is filled with multiple modes of transportation in the air, on the land and in the sea, I see no reason why another civilization would hamstring itself by restricting travel in a specific medium to a single mode of travel. The jet bike makes sense to me.

Comment: @Lexible - The fact that they never use the cycles suggests that they don't need or want them.  Unless you can fly without any effort, or run 70 miles per hour without getting tired, comparisons to our world are misguided.  They don't use what they have, and they don't seem to have what would be useful to them.  Birds with flying jet skis are like dolphins with regular jet skis.

Comment: @user14111 - Now THOSE are valid points.

Comment: @user14111 's comments seem to mirror my second comment.

Comment: @Lexible - But funnier. :)

Comment: @WadCheber *Very* fair, friend. :)

Comment: Are we sure that this is actually a Hawkman craft, and not some foreign equipment that got impounded and stored for breaking flight regulations near the palace?

Comment: @Zoredache It's identified as a Hawkman vehicle in the dialogue: "General Kala! Flash Gordon approaching!" "What do you mean, 'Flash Gordon approaching'?" "On a **Hawkman** rocket cycle..."

Comment: Surely some Hawkmen get injured, and need a way to move about during recovery.

Comment: There is every chance that, for reasons unknown, the rocket cycles (of which we only see one but there are sure to be more) was not suitable for this particular attack. I know this is speculation, but since we are mere humans and don't have access to a real Hawkman or a rocket cycle to do a more detailed comparison, then speculate we must.

Comment: Simple, this is the equivalent of a wheelchair for Hawkmen.

Comment: When Zarkov asks Ming why he attacks other planets, Ming responds "Why not?" I'd say that works well as an answer to this question, too. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (partially) answered in the film's [official novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3360604-flash-gordon).

Flash surmises that they're **for use by visitors to the Kingdom**:

> The chute took him to a dock. Holding onto the sill he had grabbed to
>   break his fall, **Flash realized he was seeing a rocket cycle, probably
>   used by friendly visitors of the Hawk Man Kingdom.** He had never before
>   seen this invention, and consequently he had no idea how to fly it.
>   But he thanked the Fates he was a fast learner.

It appears that the cycles are sufficiently well-known that they're recognisable as a Hawk Man device:

> Consequently, she became extremely deflated when the colonel from
>   Battle Control appeared on her telescreen and said, “General Kala,
>   **Flash Gordon is approaching!”**
>
> “What?” she exclaimed.
>
> “Yes, **on a Hawk Man rocket cycle**. Shall I inform His Majesty?”

Answer (score 2):

**Fun.**

Why would a human own an [electric skateboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_skateboard), or [jumping shoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerbocking)? Because its fun. Its not useful and you wouldn't want to use one when you flee from an attacker or when you attack his rockets but on your day off - why not?

Its also possible that a hawkman with a rocket cycle can do stunts he can't do without (flying upside down without stalling, flying through a storm, ...) that were never shown on screen because it wasn't important to the story.

Unfortunately I have no canon evidence (except that they sure look like they like having fun!) for all of this, but its a plausible explanation.

Also, they do flap their wings (even though only slightly) in the movie, so it could also be a "wheelchair" style of thing.

Comment: Consider adding to your answer: Range - We don't know how far a Hawkman can fly on his own. Their rocketcycles could add considerably to that distance traveled. Fatigue reduction: A Hawkman on a flying machine is much better rested than one flying on his own. Like horses, the machine is doing all the work. These are two additional answers which round out your reasoning.

Answer (score -1):

The kingdoms were not isolated. Why wouldn't there be cycles at the hawkman's palace moon? What if an entourage of people show, the transport leaves but there are one or two people left behind.

The real question you should ask is why is there breathable air between all the moons and planets of Mongo? And why can I get from one planet or moon to the other in just a few minutes yet my hair barely gets blown at top speed.

And what's with all the colored clouds?

Comment: The colored clouds are pretty.